# How to dynamically rearrange Angular material tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, tabs, angular-material2

I have a group of 7 tabs (Angular material):

```html
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 3">Content 3</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 4">Content 4</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 5">Content 5</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 6">Content 6</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 7">Content 7</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I want to set an order for the arrangement of tabs based on some conditions.

So I want **tab7, tab5, tab6, tab1, tab2 ,tab3, tab4** in a scenario.

I understand the `selectedIndex` will let us control the ACTIVE tab, but I want to control the **order of the arrangement** ( on load ) .

I have a lot of data communication between the parent and the tabs and hence am not using a *ngFor. Hence is there a solution **without** a *ngFor.

Does Angular material have the provision for this feature?

Comment: How many scenarios are you talking about? Just one or two or are they going to be able to arrange them in any order they want?

Comment: I have 3 scenarios. On load, the tabs arrangement will be done. ( not any order ) Basically hardcode the order in UI code.

Answer (score 1):

you can store all the tabs in the array and then OnInit sorts the array with the conditions you want.

or on any event onload etc.

and then, of course, loop them with the help of *ngFor directive.

Comment: The code I have added was a basic example. I have a lot of data communication and hence not using *ngFor. I am looking for a solution without the application of *ngFor

Comment: What do you mean you have a lot of data communication? As in the content of each tab is too complex to do an *ngFor?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a way to do that, but whether it is suitable for your application I don't know. `MatTab` has a position property that should do this. But it is not an `@Input`, so to use it, you would have to use `@ViewChild` to access all your tabs (or use template references from HTML if that's possible). That's kind of clumsy, but it should work. For example (pseudo-code):

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"  >
    <mat-tab #tab1 label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab #tab2 label="Tab 2">Content 1</mat-tab>
    ...
</mat-tab-group>

----

@ViewChild('tab1') tab1;
@ViewChild('tab2') tab2;
...

changeTabOrder() {
    this.tab1.position = 2;
    this.tab2.position = 1;
    ...
}
```